# twisted image transfer from client to server gives bad format error

Tags: python, image, file, twisted

I was trying to send an image file using tcp from server to client. I tried opening the file, reading it and then transporting it using self.transport.write. On the client side, when I receive data, I open a file named Image in append mode, and write to it.

client:

```
class EchoClient(protocol.Protocol):
    def dataReceived(self, data):         
        print 'writing to file'
        f = open('image.png','a')
        f.write(data)
        f.close()
```

server (inherits Protocol):

```
//somewhere in the code

     image = open(self.newdict[device_str] + attribute_str + '.png')
     data = image.read()
     image.close()
     self.comm_protocol.transport.write(data)
```

Opening the file on client side gives bad format error. Any ideas what I am doing wrong ? Is the idea to stream the image as a string bad ? If so, is there some other way I can transfer data to the client ?

Comment: You should look a little more closely than letting an image reader open it and tell you "bad format error".  What's bad about it?  Is it truncated?  Jumbled up?  Are bytes at unpredictable locations in the middle wrong?  You're expecting answers to do a *lot* of guessing here which doesn't make for the best question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to open the file in binary mode, with the 'b' flag, like `open(..., 'wb'`).

The reason that the file gets corrupted is that "text mode" does one of two things:

1. on UNIX, it does nothing.
2. on Windows, it just replaces `\n` with `\r\n`.

Now, if it's a text file, you can hardly tell the difference.  But, if it's a binary file, that byte might doesn't mean "newline" any more.  Generally, binary files are constructed from fixed-length structures, so sticking two bytes in where one is expected will cause all kinds of havoc.

Comment: I didn't get it...my client was on OS X and server on Ubuntu i.e all linux. So, text mode should work fine, no ?